Reorder the list of attributes that appear in the pop up in a Qgis2web
I have exported an openlayers map using the latest version of Qgis2web but one layer present problems in the order of the attributes fields that appear in the pop up. They do not appear in the order I have configured in Qgis attributes table.
Here is the example: All the fields that start with the word "Monto" must appear below the "Etapa N°9" field such as I configured it in the attributes table.

I have already reorder the fields in the layers.js file where the "fields labels" and "field aliases" are enlisted as well as the order that appears in the LEAT -ET PLOMER - ET VIVORATA.js file but the error still remains. How can I solved this?
lyr_LEATETPLOMERETVIVORATA_15.set('fieldLabels', {'des': 'inline label - always visible', 'long': 'inline label - always visible','Etapa N°1': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°2': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°3': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°4': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°5': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°6': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°7': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°8': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N°9': 'inline label - always visible', 'Etapa N�_1': 'inline label - always visible','1': 'inline label - always visible', '2': 'inline label - always visible', '3': 'inline label - always visible', '4': 'inline label - always visible', '5': 'inline label - always visible', '6': 'inline label - always visible', '7': 'inline label - always visible', '8': 'inline label - always visible', '9': 'inline label - always visible', '10': 'inline label - always visible', 'Ob Com': 'inline label - always visible',});

lyr_LEATETPLOMERETVIVORATA_15.set('fieldAliases', {'id': 'id', 'des': 'Descripción', 'long': 'Longitud','Etapa N°1': 'Etapa N°1', 'Etapa N°2': 'Etapa N°2', 'Etapa N°3': 'Etapa N°3', 'Etapa N°4': 'Etapa N°4', 'Etapa N°5': 'Etapa N°5', 'Etapa N°6': 'Etapa N°6', 'Etapa N°7': 'Etapa N°7', 'Etapa N°8': 'Etapa N°8', 'Etapa N°9': 'Etapa N°9', 'Etapa N�_1': 'Etapa N°10',  '1': 'Monto Etapa N°1 (USD)', '2': 'Monto Etapa N°2 (USD)', '3': 'Monto Etapa N°3 (USD)', '4': 'Monto Etapa N°4 (USD)', '5': 'Monto Etapa N°5 (USD)', '6': 'Monto Etapa N°6 (USD)', '7': 'Monto Etapa N°7 (USD)', '8': 'Monto Etapa N°8 (USD)', '9': 'Monto Etapa N°9 (USD)', '10': 'Monto Etapa N°10 (USD)', 'Ob Com': 'Observaciones',});


qgis2web exports the columns in the order they exist in the layer, even if you used "Organize Table Column", which is just a visual modification, not to the data.

To actually edit the data you need to use a toolbox process called "Refactor fields", here is a video showing its use.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDWtC6Ww2ns&ab_channel=ArnoldKilaini

Here's a link to your GitHub Issue response just for completeness - #1107.
